# Working with registered users offline WAMP

Tags: wordpress, wamp, registration

From what I've gathered, mail won't work offline using WAMP unless set up. So right now I have users that aren't activated. I'm not able to log in(or register) to wordpress as a registered user to create a specific additional functionality. Is there a way to get around this without taking it online?

Additionally can you collect more information from a registered user via additions to the form? How much access do you have to this information? The end goal is to try and keep specific information only visible to certain registered users. Only registered users that I allow would have access.

Answer (score 0):

The `Online/Offline` of WAMPServer only changes the access allowed to Apache

> Online = Apache accepts access from any ip address
>
> Offline = Apache only accepts connections from the local PC i.e. the one running WAMPServer

The reason you cannot send emails is that Windows does not have a mail server installed by default like a *nix system. If you want to send emails you have to install some sort of email server that PHP can pass emails to.

There are a number that you can use :

I prefer [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/) but it is a little complicated to configure unless you understand a bit about mail servers

Alternatively you could try [fake Sendmail for windows](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/)